# With SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery, how to get affected row count that exceeds int limit?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I'm using C# library `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` to modify SQL database. One of the scripts could modify more than `int.Max` rows. In that case, the method returns negative value. Is there any better way to get the correct row count in int64 precision? Thanks.

Comment: int.Max is `2,147,483,647` how long it takes for execution?

Comment: @un-lucky it takes about 1 hour.

Comment: I always page these kind of scripts. I call it multile times for a next block of records. It has several advantages. You can report the progress to the user. You can keep the transaction log small. You avoid timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` to the end of your query then use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` and cast the return of that to `Int64`. `ExecuteNonQuery` has a return type of `int` so there's no way to get it to handle values over int.Max directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I'm dealing with Azure SQL Datawarehouse and it seems @@rowcount is not supported... Do you know any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the end of your SQL statement:

```
select rowcount_big() as [Affected];
```

and switch `ExecuteNonQuery` with `ExecuteScalar`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set & return output parameter with **ExecuteNonQuery** as below.

> Declare @Result BIGINT OUTPUT
>
> SET @Result = @@ROWCOUNT